# How can plot power functions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot `y = x^n` for `n = 1,2,3,4,5` such that `x in [0,1]` and `y in [0,1]`.

something like this image:

[image]

When I want to set `xmin` and `xmax` to restrict the domain, the error appear!
Where is wrong!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
‎\usepackage{tikz}‎
‎\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}‎‎‎
‎\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}‎[xmin = ‎0, ymin = 0, xmax = 1‎, ymax = 1‎]‎‎
\addplot[color=red,‎smooth‎] {x‎‎};‎‎
\addplot[color=red,‎smooth‎] {x^‎2‎};‎
\addplot[color=red,‎smoo‎th‎] {x^‎3‎};‎‎
\addplot[color=red,‎smooth‎] {x^‎4‎};‎
\end{axis}
\end{‎tikzpicture}‎
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, I just saw that you did not accept a single answer to your previous questions. Just in case you don't know: one can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark left of it.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative that uses `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to repeat the `\addplot`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:1,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,...,15}{
                \addplot[red,smooth] {x^#1};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And a bit more looking like your desired plot:

[image]

With:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain=0:1,
            axis equal,
            width=8cm,height=8cm,
            xmin=-0.05,xmax=1.05,
            ymin=-0.05,ymax=1.05,
            axis y line=middle,
            axis x line=middle,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
        ]
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,20}{
                \addplot[red,smooth] {x^#1};
            }
            \draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (1,1);
            \draw[dashed] (0,1) -- (1,1);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And finally, an animation just for fun:

[image]

With:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \foreach \numPowers in {1,...,20}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                domain=0:1,
                axis equal,
                width=8cm,height=8cm,
                xmin=-0.05,xmax=1.05,
                ymin=-0.05,ymax=1.05,
                axis y line=middle,
                axis x line=middle,
                xtick=\empty,
                ytick=\empty,
            ]
                \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\numPowers}{
                    \addplot[red,smooth] {x^##1};
                }
                \draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (1,1);
                \draw[dashed] (0,1) -- (1,1);
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

If anyone could comment on why I need `##1` instead of `#1` in the `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` when its enclosed in an ordinary `\foreach`, I would be very grateful.

Comment: i. What did you use to convert to an animation?  ii. Can the PDF sequence be directly embedded as an animation in a PDF, ideally with a control?

Answer (score 5):

I hope this helps

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
{
\pgfplotsset{xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
\addplot[color=red, smooth] {x}; 
\addplot[color=blue, smooth] {x^2}; 
\addplot[color=green, smooth] {x^3};
\addplot[color=yellow, smooth] {x^4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

which will give you

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however, it looks like different with the goal plot.

Comment: @user108438 Do you mean the axis handles? I think this is what you will get with your MWE. As you mentioned, I understood from the question that you want to set your `x-y` limits. That exactly what the solution does.

Comment: @user108438 Or, if `color` is the issue, you can change it :)